# Compiling Maven Gives Me Multiple Errors

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to use maven on my project but i'm getting this error everytime and dont know how to fix it.

Below are all my settings :

Java Versoin:

```
C:\Users\TomBo\Downloads\AnimalShelterJavaGUI>java -version
java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)
```

Maven Version:

```
C:\Users\TomBo\Downloads\AnimalShelterJavaGUI>mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11- 
10T17:41:47+01:00)
Maven home: C:\Users\TomBo\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch- 
0\183.5429.30\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_181, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre
Default locale: nl_NL, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "x86", family: "dos"
```

Maven Compile:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building AnimalShelterJavaGUI 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ 
AnimalShelterJavaGUI ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\TomBo\Downloads\AnimalShelterJavaGUI\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ 
AnimalShelterJavaGUI ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered 
resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ 
AnimalShelterJavaGUI ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, 
i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 14 source files to 
C:\Users\TomBo\Downloads\AnimalShelterJavaGUI\target\classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.965 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-12T13:34:04+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/20M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler- 
plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project AnimalShelterJavaGUI: 
Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: --module-path -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e 
switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please 
read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

These are the compiling results

My JAVA_HOME dir:

[image]
My POM.xml file:

```
<groupId>groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>AnimalShelterJavaGUI</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <openfxVersion>11.0.2</openfxVersion>
    <codeVersion>11</codeVersion>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>${codeVersion}</release>
                <source>${codeVersion}</source>
                <target>${codeVersion}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I want to work with this because im going to work with jenkins.
Hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: Please do not add images, but copy/paste the output.

Comment: @JFMeier Like this?

Comment: What happens if , instead of ${codeVersion} , put the actual values?

Comment: @Filip123go tried but it wont work...

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have the wrong JDK on the PATH, because your `java -version` shows Java 8, while you try to compile with Java 11.

Check your PATH variable.

Comment: How do I change the PATH so it will be compiling in Java 11 ? is it the PATH from Maven???

Comment: No, the windows PATH variable. I guess that in your windows PATH variable (one of the system variables), you included the path to a Java 8 installation.

Comment: It is also possible that you have an installed JRE in Windows that automatically functions a standard Java (I do not know how you reliably remove that).

Comment: Exactly. It Java 8 does not understand javac parameter  --module-path. Modules were added in Java 9. So here you go ...  You have installed java 11, but system PATH points to Java 8 (multiple installations). So before executing maven, execute this:  set JAVA_HOME=set JAVA_HOME=c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1-11.0.2\

Comment: @MitjaGustin Can I not just delete Java 8? So I have only Java 11

Comment: Of course you can. But you have to uninstall it, or registry and PATH will still point to now non-existent folder.